# 403/Forbidden when trying to login to the Kibana web interface using the built-in kibana user

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

Inspired by this docker-compose file:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html

I am starting an elasticsearch/kibana cluster

I have modified the above docker-compose file to enable basic authentication (below only showing the first es master):

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/instance.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/instance.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ca.crt
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./certs/instance/instance.key:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/instance.key
      - ./certs/instance/instance.crt:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/instance.crt
      - ./certs/ca/ca.crt:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ca.crt
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
```

And based on:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html#set-built-in-user-passwords

I have set the default **password** for all built-in users (`elastic`, `kibana`, etc.) to `changeme` by running:

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

But when I try to login http://localhost:5601 using `kibana/changeme`:

[image]

I get:

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}
```

I have verified that the kibana user has access to elasticsearch:

```
$ curl -u kibana:changeme localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "es01",
  "cluster_name" : "es-docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "lhaaYSSFT4Cp2vUMceb0MA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.7.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "81a1e9eda8e6183f5237786246f6dced26a10eaf",
    "build_date" : "2020-05-12T02:01:37.602180Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
```

But how do I login to the kibana *webinterface* (which I assume needs another set of credentials, unless there is a default user)?

Based on:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.7/using-kibana-with-security.html

I have this in **/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml** in the kibana container:

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://es01:9200"]
xpack.security.enabled: "true"
elasticsearch.username: kibana
elasticsearch.password: changeme
xpack.security.encryptionKey: "something_at_least_32_characters"
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try login using elastic username and elastic password.Change in the kibana yml as well and then restart.